# How does unordered_map use its hash internally?

Tags: c++, hash

How does unordered_map use the hash function internally to access a bucket that belongs to a key?

std::hash returns a size_t type, that may be larger than the number of the buckets that exist in the container. How is the returned hash value mapped to a bucket index?

Does a typical unordered_map implementation perform a modulo of the returned hash by size() or by max_size(), or does something more complicated happen?

Comment: Facetiously speaking; it can do what it wants so long as it obeys the standard. Why not look at your vendor's stl source code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does a typical unordered_map implementation perform a modulo of the returned hash by size() or by max_size(), or does something more complicated happen?

Almost. The modulo would be `bucket_count()`, since that's the number of buckets in the hash table.

The standard doesn't require this to be done with a modulo operation, just that the `bucket()` function maps key values to the range `[0,bucket_count)` in some way, and that keys with equivalent hashes map to the same bucket. The modulus of the hash is the most straightforward way to do that.